# Titles with PLplot, OCaml

Tags: plot, ocaml

I would like to put titles to my graph with the PLplot bindings in OCaml. So far, my code looks like this:

```
let simple_example g filename =
  let p =
    P.init (0.0, -2.0) (10.0, 2.0) `greedy (`svg `core) ~filename:filename
  in

  P.plot ~stream:p [P.func `blue g (0.0, 10.0) ~step:0.001];
  P.finish ~stream:p ();
  ;;
```

I had a look at the `plplot.mli` file and tried to use the `text` an `text_outside` functions, unsuccessfully. I know there is the `Quick_plot` module, which enables me to write titles easily, but I would like to avoid it as I lose a lot of other options with it.

**Edit.**

I had a look at the "canonical" examples, without success (here : http://plplot.sourceforge.net/docbook-manual/plplot-html-5.11.1/ocaml_howto.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get help from [PLplot](http://plplot.sourceforge.net/examples.php?demo=01&lbind=Ocaml) web site which provides example using ocaml among other languages.

I managed to display a label to the parabol drawing :

```
      let simple_example () =
      let xs = Array.init 21 (fun xi -> float xi -. 10.0) in
      let ys = Array.map (fun x -> x**2.0) xs in
      plinit ();
      plenv (-10.0) 10.0 0.0 100.0 0 0;
      plline xs ys;
      pllab "(x)" "(y)" "#frPLplot Example 1 - y=x#u2";
      plend();
      ();;
```

And if you want to use the Plot module from Plplot, you just have to add this into the list you give to P.plot like below :

```
let simple_example g filename =
  let p =
    P.init (0.0, -2.0) (10.0, 2.0) `greedy (`svg `core) ~filename:filename
  in

  P.plot ~stream:p [P.func `blue g (0.0, 10.0) ~step:0.001; P.text `blue 0. 0. "function"];
  P.finish ~stream:p ();
  ;;
```

Comment: Thank you, I thought about using this, but I was looking for a solution using the syntax P.Init, P.plot, P.Finish it seems much more readable to me.

Answer (score 2):

The function `P.label` should do what you want:

https://github.com/hcarty/ocaml-plplot/blob/d261e5ec21274ca1a7065e16ab57e87617f8dfcb/src/plplot.mli#L284

This function is the `Plot` module's equivalent to `pllab`.